# Git post-rewrite not executed

Tags: git, git-rebase, githooks

I have an executable `.git/hooks/post-rewrite` file, which for testing purposes
has the following lines in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Notice: post-rewrite hook is running"
```

My understanding is that the `post-rewrite` hook runs after operations that rewrite commit history, such as `rebase` and `git commit --amend`.

Indeed, running `git commit --ammend` will print the message to `stdout` after commiting. However, when I do `git rebase master` from a branch that is behind `master`, or `git pull --rebase`, nothing is printed to `stdout`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I do `git rebase master` for a branch that is **behind** master;
>   or `git pull --rebase`

You are not **rewriting** any commits; you are fast-forwarding; so basically your branch just points to another commit. None of the commits are rewritten.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. 

Is there a way to run a hook after a `git pull --rebase` even if it only fast-forwards?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't ever used git hooks (yet). I looked around in the doc but didn't really find one that would do that... maybe ask another question :)